# Improve time for querying installed applications

Tags: android

I made an app which can be used to acquire installed app info, such as app name, package name, installed path ...etc. The problem is , when it first run the query for the installed apps info on the machine, it takes a while, is there any way to solve/ease this kind of problem ?

Comment: Your app performance is influenced by the number of installed apps. By the way, **what shall we do with the provided apk**? It would be better to provide **some code** to analyze! Anyway, **ProGuard** can optimize your code, if properly set.

Comment: you are relying on data handled externally to your app, unfortunately I think you can't do much to improve the speed

Comment: @Der Golem @ sherpya   it's more a design and control flow problem. I am not trying to accelerate the program execution speed, but trying to improve user experience.

Comment: To "optimize", as per your question title,  means to "accelerate", or increase performances. And this improves the user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do:

1. As @Shereef said, you should run your long-running job in a thread off the main thread.
2. You should run that Thread in a Service so that you don't lose progress during configuration changes, app quits. The app can then send a notification to the user in the case where they got frustrated waiting.
3. To reduce/eliminate that frustration, you should update the UI of your app as the results become available. Users are much happier to allow long running operations to continue if they can see that progress is being made.
4. You should allow users to search or drill down into the data even before it's all available. If they're busy looking at detail of one app while the rest of the data loads, then they'll never know that it took a long time to load all the app data.
5. Consider saving the data to a database as it's obtained so that the user only has to pay the acquisition cost once.
6. Also consider hiding that database behind a ContentProvider.
7. You can schedule an Alarm to restart your Service to update the data in the background.

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    void run() {
        // Your code here but not anything that talks to the UI
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            void run() {
                // Talk to the UI here

            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: I think the main problem is : it take a great amount of time to query the installed app... I think I need to figure out a way to cut down the user waiting time to improve the user experience.

Comment: Do you need the list immediately on startup of your app? Otherwise, you can start retrieve the list in the background when your app starts up, and are likely to have the full list before the user asks for it. You can also handle events that tell you when apps are installed/uninstalled so that your list is always current.

Comment: Reto add your answer I think he would like it